# Is it theoretically plausible for a non-piecewise function to exhibit both an inflection point and a vertical tangent at the same value

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a real non-piecewise function defined in the interval $A$ and $x_0$ an interior point of $A$ . I am curious about the possibility of such a function exhibiting both an inflection point and a vertical tangent at $x_0$.

My understanding is that an inflection point typically marks a change in the concavity of the function, while a vertical tangent indicates a singularity where the derivative tends to infinity. These characteristics seem inherently distinct, raising questions about their concurrent existence within a single function at a specific interior point.

I have found two functions that satisfy those criteria they are both piecewise. namely :

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
  \sqrt{-x} ,  & \text{ x is less or equal to 0  } \\
 \sqrt{x}  , & \text{ x is greater than 0 }
\end{cases}$
[graph of $f$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkkRZ.png)

$g(x)= \begin{cases} \sqrt{1-x^2} , & \text{x is less than1  } \\ -\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}, & \text{x is greater than 1 } \end{cases}$
[graph of $g$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el58t.png)

I am still unsure of the possibility that I have missed something.

Comment: $h(x)=x^{1/3}$ has a vertical tangent and has an inflexion point in $(0,0)$

Comment: that seems to work great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first function may be expressed as $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$, which isn't a piecewise function.

But... $|x|$ is itself a piecewise function.

If you're still not convinced, $g(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$ will do: in fact, it has a very similar graph to that of $f(x)$.

Comment: Well the function you provided is not the same with "my" f . I thought raticals had a possitive domain only , thanks for answering

Comment: It is the same function.